# Como trabalhar com ui-mask em input angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="addState(myForm.$valid)" novalidate >

        <input ng-model="data.cnpj" type="number" ui-mask="999.999.999-99" placeholder="CNPJ" required ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="12" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}[-\.\/]?+$/">
 </form>
```

O que é preciso colocar no controller para o  ui-mask funcionar?

Eu tentei isso mas não deu certo.

```
mainAppControllers.controller('Ctrl', ['myservice','$rootScope','$scope', '$routeParams', '$location','$timeout',
function(myservice, $rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $location,$timeout ){
```

Comment: já tentou importar o "ui-utils" ou "ui.mask"  ?

Comment: Já, não rolou :(

Comment: @ClaudiaMardegan Você carregou o `ui-utils.js` e importou o `ui-utils`? Aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: Não aparece erro, eu consegui fazer ele pegar, mas ele so funciona no 1 item no segundo não criou a mascara.

     <input ng-model="data.cnpj" type="text" ui-mask="999.999.999-99"  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}[-\.\/]?+$/">
    <input ng-model="data.data" type="text" ui-mask="00/00/0000" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}[-\.\/]?+$/">

Comment: @AndréRibeiro qual seu linkedin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olhando pelo seu comentário, se a primeira tag

```
<input ng-model="data.cnpj" type="text" ui-mask="999.999.999-99" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}[-\.\/]?+$/">
```

funcionou, altere a segunda para

```
<input ng-model="data.data" type="text" ui-mask="99/99/9999" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}[-\.\/]?+$/">
```