# Máscara de data com hora

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Como faço uma Mascara para um input text com o formato **xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx:xx** usando angular?
Seria a dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto e segundos.

```
<div class="form-group filtro">
   <label class="" for="endDate">Data de Criação</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="criterioDeBusca.dataCriacao" ui-mask="99/99/9999 99:99:99" ui-mask-placeholder-char="_"/>                         
</div>
                   <table>
                     <tbody>
                      <tr dir-paginate="atividade in atividades | filter:criterioDeBusca | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoDaOrdenacao|itemsPerPage:5">
                        <td>{{atividade.dataCriacao | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Seria isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48598/5878

Comment: Eu utilizei o ui-mask para trabalhar com mascaras no angularjs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask), e configure sempre `ng-model` para não acabar com um erro estranho na tela, ***exemplo minimo***:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.mask']);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-mask/1.8.7/mask.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" ui-mask="99/99/9999 99:99:99" ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" />
</div>
```

Comment: apliquei seu exemplo e funcionou a mascara, mas não está mais permitindo filtrar como estava anteriormente, e não deu nenhum erro, apenas parou de funcionar. Sabe o que pode ser? Coloquei o trecho na pergunta

Comment: @Isa na mascara está assim: dia, mes, ano, horas, minutos e segundos, e no sua edição em date: está dia, mes, ano, horas e minutos? cade os segundos, ou tira da formatação um ou coloca um, entendeu?

Comment: foi falta de atenção minha, depois que fiz a perguntei vi que esqueci de aplicar a alteração na td, mas ainda sim, não filtra corretamente

Comment: @Isa, eu não consigo reproduzir seu exemplo, porque, falta código na sua pergunta, e também porque deveria ser aberta outra questão, porque a sua duvida primária é sobre máscara e não sobre filtro entendeu?, será que pode fechar essa questão, apostando em alguma das respostas e abrir outra falando sobre filtro?

Comment: vou fazer isso. Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso [ui-mask](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html).

```
<input type="text" ui-mask="99/99/9999 99:99:99" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" />
```

Porém o `ui-mask` não cuidará de nenhuma validação de data, apenas o formato da String.

Para validar a data eu uso o `datepicker` do [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Mas caso você deseja formatar apenas um `timestamp` em formatado para uma dara legivel você pode usar o filtro padrãod o angular.

```
{{ dataEmTimestamp | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}
```